# Alternative to com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementImpl

Tags: java, sharepoint, soap

I'm working on a java application (in netbeans) that uses data in a SharePoint list. I follow this tutorial to retrieve data from SharePoint: http://davidsit.wordpress.com/2010/02/10/reading-a-sharepoint-list-with-java-tutorial/

The good thing is, it works. The bad news is, I get a warning which I can't seem to fix.

a condensed snippet:

```
Lists service = new Lists();
ListsSoap port = service.getListsSoap();
GetListItemsResponse.GetListItemsResult result = port.getListItems(
                "myListName", "", null, null, "9999", null, "" );
Object resultNode = result.getContent().get( 0 );
NodeList list = ((com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementImpl)data)
                .getElementsByTagName( "myTag" );
```

It is this last line, that is causing the following warning:

```
warning: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementImpl 
is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
```

Obviously, I need to find an alternative to this ElementImpl class. I tried googling, looking at docs, but haven't found anything useful.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why not just cast to

```
org.w3c.dom.Element
```

It is very unlikely, that you need any property from the Xerces implementation, so just stick with the DOM API types, which is what you're already doing by referencing `org.w3c.dom.NodeList`

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I'm kinda new to all this soap/wsdl business, and sometimes miss elementary stuff like this.

Answer (score -1):

A better alternative which allows using the class is adding a dependency to jaxp-ri library and importing the class from the jar instead of jre internal.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.parsers/jaxp-ri